# What is "$(SourceDir)" in Microsoft Team Foundation Server?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm working with Microsoft Team Foundation Server and MSDN has been fantastic so far with providing all the information I've needed and so much more--except in one spot.

I'm creating an automated build and under   Workspace > Working Folders > Build Agent Folder, it has "$(SourceDir)" as default.

I can't seem to figure out what that is actually referencing.  Is it pointing toward the folder that the solution is in, or something else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is well explained in this article: [List of variables like $(SourceDir)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/e4ba62f4-2fae-46d8-b787-c448ffa88af9/).

> For the workspace mapping dialog you can only use two variables to
>   help with expansion:
>
> $(BuildDir) - Expands to BuildAgent.BuildDirectory
>
> $(SourceDir) - Expands to $(BuildDir)\Sources by default
>
> The directory "Sources" is not hard-coded and may be changed by
>   modifying the TfsBuildService.exe.config file on the build agent. If
>   you open that file there will be an application setting called
>   "SourcesSubDirectory". If you need a shorter path you may change this
>   key to something like "s" instead of "Sources". If you made this
>   change then the $(SourceDir) variable would expand to $(BuildDir)\s.

Comment: Thank you for this link, it explains it much better.

Comment: This link referenced by this answer pertains to TFS2008. In TFS2010 there is no TfsBuildService.exe.config file in the specified location. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027351/how-does-the-build-agend-folder-work-on-the-edit-build-workspace for an answer relevant to TFS2010.