# How does the build Agent Folder work on the Edit Build Workspace?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

My build cannot pick up some of the projects in my application.
They are stored in their own projects in TFS source control.
I group them together in the Edit Build workspace;

These are the mappings:
[image: These are the mappings]

The Build Agent folder does not let me simply put `$(SourceDir)`. What is the impact of appending a folder name at the end as above?
How do I get the Build Agent to pick up the projects from the correct folder locations?

Currently I get these error messages;

```
8 error(s), 3 warning(s)
$/STAS/Timesheet/Timesheet/Timesheet.sln - 8 error(s), 3 warning(s), View Log File
 C:\Builds\4\STAS\Timesheet\Sources\Timesheet\Timesheet.sln.metaproj: The project file "C:\Builds\4\STAS\Timesheet\Sources\Timesheet\..\..\..\..\StandardClassLibrary\StandardClassLibrary\StandardClassLibrary.csproj" was not found.
 C:\Builds\4\STAS\Timesheet\Sources\Timesheet\Timesheet.sln.metaproj: The project file "C:\Builds\4\STAS\Timesheet\Sources\Timesheet\..\..\..\EmailMessageRecord\EmailMessageRecord\EmailMessageRecord.csproj" was not found.
```

Comment: This is used if you have multiple resources IE references to load for your solution to work. This will in fact expose those files to your solution. See : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh190721.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly how the feature is meant to be used. The `$(Sourcedir)` macro is replaced by the Build Agent path (as configured on the Build Agent):

[image: BuildAgent Properties]

Whichever path is configured here is placed into `$(Sourcedir)` and whatever you additionally configure in the mapping is used to create the final destination.

So what happens is that these solutions will all be downloaded to their own sub directory under the build working directory. The only think you'll need to look out for is that relative paths between folders in source control or in your local mapping need to match up with the destination folder structure you choose int he build definition's workspace mapping.

Comment: So how do I get $(SourceDir)/StandardClassLibrary to map to the local directory? Currently the build is not find the csprog.

Comment: I have put the error message I am getting in my question. The build is not finding the libraries, how do I fix that?

Comment: That final paragraph made me think that I needed the same folder structure in the Build Agent Folder as in my local file system. It took me a while to figure that out, but when I tried it, it worked!

Comment: This seems to apply to TFS2010, though neither the question nor the answer state what version it applies to. I don't know if it also applies to versions of TFS beyond 2010, though it may well do so.

Comment: Added tags, this is true for all versions since 2010.